# Lightning:select size of biggest option

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

Is there a way to have a `lightning:select` auto sizing to the biggest of its `option` ?

```
<lightning:select>
   <option value="1">short name</option>
   <option value="2">longest name of options</option>
</lightning:select>
```

Comment: I think it automatically handle it, Are you facing any issue?

Comment: add screenshot and your code. this element will take parent element width so if you specify slds-grid for external div it will take that width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `lightning:select` lightning component includes a select input inside a container.

Here's the code automatically added:

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
   <label class="slds-form-element__label">
      <span class=""></span>
   </label>
   <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-grow">
      <div class="slds-select_container">
         <select class="slds-select">
            <option value="1">short name</option>
            <option value="2">longest name of options</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The container with the class `slds-select_container` is displayed as a block which takes all the width available. So, you have to change this.

First, add a custom class to your input like this:

```
<lightning:select class="select-auto-width">
```

Now, in your component style, you have to add:

```
.THIS .select-auto-width > .slds-form-element__control > .slds-select_container{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but I just have a visual glitch: the right edge of the open dropdown has no black line

Comment: No problem. I don't seet any difference between the default input and the one modified.

Answer (score 3):

No need to create custom CSS.  You can use `class="slds-show_inline-block"`.